# Matlab/Simulink : Replace a column in a matrix in Simulink

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

I just want to know if an easy method exists to replace entirely a column of a matrix by an another one ? I can do it by using recursively a concatenate block but it seems a bit onerous...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now an answer for Simulink, this basically implements the same as `M=magic(5);M(:,2)=1:5`

[image]

Comment: But this code doest not work on my version of Matlab (2013b) ?? I have this error message : **Invalid input dimensions specified for input port <U> of 'test/Assignment1'. The signal should be a scalar or of dimension 2**

Comment: @user2412542: This screenshot was taken with 13b, it is working. Did you uncheck the 'Interpred vector parameters as 1-D'?

Comment: Ok now it's working... Should have look for this option before. In any cases, thank you !!